# Converting PIL.Image to skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image, opencv

I have 2 modules in my project: first works with image in bytes format, second requires skimage object. I need to combine them.

I have this code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import skimage.io

area = (...)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
image = Image.crop(area)
image = skimage.io.imread(image)
```

But i get this error:
[image]

How can i convert an image (object/variable) to skimage? I don't necessarily need PIL Image, this is just one way to work with bytes image, cause i need to crop my image

Thanks!

Comment: It's much more useful to insert the error text than a screenshot. Search engines are much more likely to read text, and the text in that screenshot appears so small that it's difficult for most humans to read, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Scikit-image** works with images stored as Numpy arrays - same as **OpenCV** and **wand**. So, if you have a `PIL Image`, you can make a Numpy array for **scikit-image** like this:

```
# Make Numpy array for scikit-image from "PIL Image"
na = np.array(YourPILImage)
```

Just in case you want to go the other way, and make a `PIL Image` from a Numpy array, you can do:

```
# Make "PIL Image" from Numpy array
pi = Image.fromarray(na)
```

Comment: But how skimage can load this array? I mean, skimage.io.imread() takes str type - image file path @mark-setchell

Comment: If you have a file on disk called `"image.jpg"`, you need `image = skimage.io.imread("image.jpg")`

Comment: no, i dont have it. i already have an image object i work with, and it can't be saved as file on server to load it for skimage. That is why i'm asking. It just an object image variable during the program @Mark-Setchell

Comment: I don't understand what you have. Let's suppose you have something called `"thing"` so please show the output from `print(type(thing))` and please show the first few bytes of `thing`. Thank you.

Comment: if print(image_bytes) then

b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07 etc

Comment: sorry, maybe my english is too bad to explain what i need :(

Comment: @Neighbourhood: I fail to see what the problem is. Did you try Mark’s code? Where you have `image = skimage.io.imread(image)` instead use `image = np.array(image)`.