# Is it possible to translate this OpenCV into Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I was wondering if I can translate this *opencv-python* method into *Pillow* as I am forced furtherly to process it in *Pillow*.

A workaround I thought about would be to just save it with *OpenCV* and load it after with *Pillow* but I am looking for a cleaner solution, because I am using the `remove_background()` method's output as input for each frame of a GIF. Thus, I will read and write images **N * GIF_frames_count** times for no reason.

The method I want to convert from *Pillow* to *opencv-python*:

```
def remove_background(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)

    # Convert to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Threshold input image as mask
    mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # Negate mask
    mask = 255 - mask

    # Apply morphology to remove isolated extraneous noise
    # Use border constant of black since foreground touches the edges
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # Anti-alias the mask -- blur then stretch
    # Blur alpha channel
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0, 0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

    # Linear stretch so that 127.5 goes to 0, but 255 stays 255
    mask = (2 * (mask.astype(np.float32)) - 255.0).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

    # Put mask into alpha channel
    result = img.copy()
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    result[:, :, 3] = mask

    return result
```

Code taken from: [how to remove background of images in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63001988/12339258)

Comment: Why not keep this and just convert the result to a PIL Image? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075430/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell this should work. I have tried it out though, and it writes the image with a blueish tint. Just to be clear, I have returned `Image.fromarray(result)` and then called `.save("new-image.png")` on it.

Comment: Change the last `cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA` to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA` as PIL uses RGB ordering and OpenCV uses BGRA.

Comment: Sorry, I should have thought to mention that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell nice! If you'd like to give an answer so I can mark it as solution would be great!

Comment: I can't at the moment, but you're welcome to summarise it and add it as an answer yourself - then you can accept it and grab the points.

Comment: You might reference the person who wrote that code you are borrowing or link to their answer and give it an up-vote, if you have not already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than re-writing all the code using **PIL** equivalents, you could adopt the *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it"* maxim, and simply convert the `Numpy array` that the existing code produces into a `PIL Image` that you can use for your subsequent purposes.

That is this described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075430/2836621) answer, which I'll paraphrase as:

```
# Make "PIL Image" from Numpy array
pi = Image.fromarray(na)
```

Note that the linked answer refers to `scikit-image` (which uses RGB ordering like **PIL**) rather than **OpenCV**, so there is the added wrinkle that you will also need to reorder the channels from BGRA to RGBA, so the last couple of lines will look like:

```
...
...
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask
pi = Image.fromarray(result)
```